# Debian: understanding /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: linux, debian

I'm pretty new in Debian world. I just got a private virtual server to host my websites, and i'm currently learning how to correctly secure a webserver.

If I understand well, when doing apt-get update && apt-get upgrade, apt will retrieve updates of my installed packages in the repositories listed in /etc/apt/sources.list. My sources.list looks like this :

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

And here come my questions :)

1. Can I remove the lines starting with "deb-src"? Am I correct if I say I don't need packages sources unless I want to modify them myself (which, obviously, i'm just not able to do)?
2. What's the point of having several repositories (http://http.debian.net/debian and http://security.debian.org/)? I keep reading documentations about apt, but I don't find any explanations. Are there any packages that are in security.debian.org that are not in http.debian.net/debian? And vice versa?
3. after the repository URI comes the component. I understand the differences between wheezy / stable / testing etc. But what's the differences between wheezy and wheezy/updates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`deb-src` is for source packages. You would use those for cross compiling and other neat dev stuff.

The security repo is where the security related updates are stored.

Lastly the updates repo is for updates released after the distribution is live, I believe.

Take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

And this SE question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/why-is-there-a-separate-package-repository-for-debian-security-updates

Comment: Thx for the answer and the SE question, very informative. It's unclear for me what the difference is btw wheezy and wheezy-updates.

Comment: @PGBI, They are different repository branches. Wheezy should be "V1.0" Debian software; Wheezy-Updates should be "V1.1" to current, if you will. The reasons the SE question sited that the security repo is separated are the same reasons that the updates repo is separated.

Comment: So If I say that on wheezy branch i'll get what we can call "V1.0.x" updates and that on wheezy-updates i get "V1.x" updates, am I correct?

Comment: @PGBI, Very roughly, yes. Wheezy-updates obviously wouldn't be limited to "V1.x", though, it could be "V2.x" or "V3.x" etc. if the package has a new version. Think of wheezy though, as implicitly legacy.